# Stored Procedure That Return Different Table According To Parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, parameters

I want to write a stored procedure that takes @FirmId as a parameter and I will use the related table according to this parameter.

What I want to obtain (but I don't want to use) is something like that:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spFirmDetailGetByFirmId 
    @FirmId AS INT
AS
BEGIN
    IF @FirmId = 1
        SELECT * FROM Firm1
    ELSE IF @FirmId = 2
        SELECT * FROM Firm2
        .
        .
        .
        .
    ELSE IF @FirmId = 1000
        SELECT * FROM Firm1000
END
```

And also I don't want to create query string and then EXEC it, something like that in the fallowing code block. Because the real query is too complex and it will be very hard to manage if I use this option.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spFirmDetailGetByFirmId 
    @FirmId AS INT
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @Query AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT * FROM Firm'
    SET @Query = @Query + CAST(@FirmId AS NVARCHAR(10))
    EXEC(@Query)
END
```

Is there any other option?
Thanks.

Comment: I don't believe there are any other options, but if the tables are the same but for the numbers, then a "solution" might be to put it all into one table with the numbers as an identifier. Failing that, the dynamic SQL seems to be your best option, as annoying as it might be to rewrite.

Comment: The only other option (and the best one) is to redesign your tables so that there is just one `firm` table with a `FirmId` column.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I know the design is bad but unfortunately the db is not under my control. It is designed by another company and I just have to use it like this for my report screens.

Comment: If all tables have the same columns create a view and add a computed colum on it for FirmId

Comment: @Byron How can I create such a view? There are more than one hundred firms and this number can be change in the future. Can you give me an example please.

Comment: Is the structure of all `Firm`-tables identical (and will be in future)?

Comment: @Shnugo Yes the tables are identical and will be kept identical.

Comment: Btw: Why a down-vote? The OP clearly shows, that the *common approaches* are clear (with code examples!) and asks for alternatives. What's wrong with this? Voted up for compensation...

Comment: Can you explain why the dynamic SQL approach is "hard to manage"?  My guess is that you want to define the query with place holders for the table name, do a single `replace` to substitute in the table name, and then execute the resulting statement.  But I'm not sure if that works for you.

Comment: @Justin Cave It can be hard to modify and test dynamic queries when you want to change something in a complex query. It is always open to errors. And there are another things that must be thought like performance and security issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I take your *Yes the tables are identical and will be kept identical* to suggest two approaches:

```
DECLARE @Firm VARCHAR(10)='Firm3';

SELECT * FROM Firm1 WHERE @Firm='Firm1'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Firm2 WHERE @Firm='Firm2'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Firm3 WHERE @Firm='Firm3'
[...]
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Firm1000 WHERE @Firm='Firm1000'
```

The second is:

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)='SELECT * FROM ####';
SET @query=REPLACE(@query,'####',@Firm);
EXEC (@query)
```

The second could be used with a `VIEW` (in place of the `@query`), where you could read the VIEW's definition into the variable and create an `ALTER VIEW`-statement dynamically... Your procedure would call the same VIEW (but this would crash with parallel calls!)

Answer (score 1):

This code can by use in a stored procedure to automatic create the view, every time you need to add columns

```
declare @tableId  int
declare @columns varchar(max)
declare @tablesCount int
declare @tableName varchar(255)
declare @query varchar(255)
declare @id int
declare @result nvarchar(max)

set @columns = ''
set @tableName = 'Firm'
set @id = 1
set @result = ''

--Base table
select @tableId = object_id from sys.tables where name =@tableName
--Count how many table with the 'same name'
select @tablesCount= count(*) from sys.tables where name like @tableName+'%'
--Build Columns to add in the view
select  @columns =@columns+name+', 'from Sys.columns where object_id = @tableId

--Drop View
set @result = 'Drop view  vw_'+@tableName
exec sp_executesql @result
set @result=''

while(@id<=@tablesCount)
Begin 
 declare @idVarchar varchar(10)
 set @idVarchar = cast(@id as varchar(10))

 set @result =@result+'Select '+@columns+@idVarchar+' as FirmId from '+@tableName+@idVarchar
 +'
Union all
'
 set @id =@id+1
End
set @result  = substring(@result, 1, len(@result)-12)
set @result='Create view vw_'+@tableName+' as
'+@result


exec sp_executesql @result
```

There is a another choice to this, you can also use sp_helpText to get the current definition of the view and append only add new table identifier

Comment: Thanks for your sharing. It is an interesting way to use sys.tables. I am going to try to optimize your query for my real life case.

Comment: the idea of this kind of procedure, is to will be used for the administrator, for example  i have a procedure who create a file group, create some tables on it and archive the old data, after that it mark the files as readonly and rebuilt a view used in historical report